# Add blank space to a string in trigger

Tags: apex, string

So I have a trigger that's working well - it looks at some multi-select fields on a Job object and then matches those to Accounts with the same values, pulling in the Account Manager's email address.

The only issue is that it pulls them in like so: ben@aol.com,tammy@msn.com,roger@hotlink.net.

When I really need it to pull in as: ben@aol.com, tammy@msn.com, roger@hotlink.net.

However, adding that extra space in there has proven quite difficult.  I've tried adding it after the comma and as a separate piece, but it doesn't work or the code breaks.

Any help appreciated, code is below, Thanks!

```
  trigger CCPEmailTrigger on AVTRRT__Job__c (before insert, before update) {
  Set<ID> accIds = new Set<ID>();
  Set<ID> pipelineIds = new Set<ID>();
  Map<ID, String> accNameMap = new Map<ID, String>();
  Map<ID, String> pipeLineNameMap = new Map<ID, String>();
  List<Account> matchingAccounts = new List<Account>();
  String clientOppMatchString = '';
  String pipeLineMatchString = '';
  for(AVTRRT__Job__c job : Trigger.new) {
    if(job.Publish_CCP__c && (Trigger.isInsert || (Trigger.isUpdate && !Trigger.oldMap.get(job.id).Publish_CCP__c))) {
      accIds.add(job.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c);
      pipelineIds.add(job.Pipeline__c);
    }
  }
  for(Account acc : [Select Name from Account Where ID IN :accIds]) {
    accNameMap.put(acc.id, acc.Name);
    if(clientOppMatchString.contains(acc.Name)) {
      continue;
    }
    if(clientOppMatchString != '') {
      clientOppMatchString =  clientOppMatchString + ',\''+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(acc.Name) + '\'';
    } else {
      clientOppMatchString =  '\''+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(acc.Name) + '\'';
    }
  }
  for(Pipeline__c pipeLine : [Select Name From Pipeline__c]) {
    pipeLineNameMap.put(pipeLine.ID, pipeLine.Name);
    if(pipeLineMatchString.contains(pipeLine.Name)) {
      continue;
    }
    if(pipeLineMatchString == '') {
      pipeLineMatchString =  '\''+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(pipeLine.Name) + '\'';
    } else {
      pipeLineMatchString =  pipeLineMatchString + ',\''+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(pipeLine.Name) + '\'';
    }
  }
  System.debug('Query =>' + 'Select ID, Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c, Pipelines_for_Job_Opportunities__c, Account_Manager_eMail_1__c ' +
                       + ' from Account Where CCP_Status__c = \'Active\' AND Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c includes (' + clientOppMatchString + ') AND' + 
                       + ' Pipelines_for_Job_Opportunities__c includes (' + pipeLineMatchString + ')');
  if(!pipeLineNameMap.isEmpty() && !accNameMap.isEmpty()) {
    matchingAccounts = Database.query('Select ID, Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c, Pipelines_for_Job_Opportunities__c, Account_Manager_eMail_1__c ' +
                       + ' from Account Where CCP_Status__c = \'Active\' AND Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c includes (' + clientOppMatchString + ') AND' + 
                       + ' Pipelines_for_Job_Opportunities__c includes (' + pipeLineMatchString + ')');
  }
  String emailStr;             
  for(AVTRRT__Job__c job : Trigger.new) {
    emailStr = '';
    if(job.Publish_CCP__c && (Trigger.isInsert || (Trigger.isUpdate && !Trigger.oldMap.get(job.id).Publish_CCP__c))) {
      // Loop Through each account and find matching accounts
      for(Account acc : matchingAccounts) {
        if(
          acc.Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c.contains(accNameMap.get(job.AVTRRT__Account_Job__c)) &&
          acc.Pipelines_for_Job_Opportunities__c.contains(pipeLineNameMap.get(job.Pipeline__c)) &&
          acc.Account_Manager_eMail_1__c != null
        ) {
          if(emailStr != '') {
            emailStr = emailStr + ',';
          }
          emailStr = emailStr + acc.Account_Manager_eMail_1__c;
        }
      }
      job.eMails_for_CCP_Job_Op_eMail__c = emailStr;
    }
  }             
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
      if(emailStr != '') {
        emailStr = emailStr + ',';
      }
```

to

```
      if(emailStr != '') {
        emailStr = emailStr + ', '; // <-- add space following the comma
      }
```

That should put the desired extra space in for you.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev - I tried that once before but it didn't add the space?  I'll implement again and see if it was just an accident the first time.